# How to write proper selector in rvest

Tags: r, selector, rvest

I am using `rvest` package to download information from website http://www.wp.pl/ but I'm only interested in links with special tag `data-cluster` like this one

```
<a data-cluster="3" href="http://wp.tv/i,nowe-prawo-drogowe-juz-latem-nowelizacja-czeka-na-podpis,mid,1659098,klip.html" title="Bat na kierowców już latem? &quot;To będzie trzęsienie ziemi&quot;" data-st-mtype="3">
<img src="http://y.wpimg.pl/i/ivar/G/201503/1426152344_a.jpg" data-src="http://y.wpimg.pl/i/ivar/G/201503/1426152344_a.jpg" alt="" height="191" width="332">
<h3>Bat na kierowców już latem? "To będzie trzęsienie ziemi"</h3>
</a>
```

Any ideas on how to specify selector in `html_nodes()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly use xpath:

```
library(rvest)
html('<a blah="1">123</a><a href="">345</a><a href="">789</a><a blah="2" href="">345</a>') %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//a[@blah]')
# [[1]]
# <a blah="1">123</a> 
#   
# [[2]]
# <a blah="2" href="">345</a> 
#   
#   attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLNodeSet
```

Comment: The equivalent CSS is even simpler: "a[blah]"

Comment: FWIW I think it's a good idea to get in the habit of doing `.//` in your xpath so they're anchored at the current node, not at the top of the document

Comment: Thanks @hadley. You mean like this: `html('<a><b></b></a><a></a>') %>% html_nodes(xp = '//a') %>% html_nodes(xp = './/b')`?

Comment: Yeah - it'll save you some head scratching at some point in the future